# The application settings are not allowed to be edited

Tags: visual-studio-code

Have installed the Visual Studio Code version 1.26 on my windows 10 64 bit machine. The application gets launched perfectly fine. But when I navigate to file-preferences-settings the following issues arise:

I can search and copy the required setting to my user settings but I can't edit it.

eg: I search for the font size settings and copy it but can't change the font size from 14 to 16. The system shows the error when I copy a setting.

I uninstalled the application many times and reinstalled it with a fresh download but the error persists.

Works fine in my ubuntu 18.04 operating system 
Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: So... What's the error message?

Comment: Actually, we have to copy the setting within the starting and ending curly braces provided but when I copy the settings it gets copied outside the braces and hence under the problem tab the following error message shows up:'Unexpected end of a string

Answer (score 0):

The default user settings cannot be edited. To customize settings, you have to copy and paste the setting you want to change into either your user settings or workspace settings and make the changes there.

Comment: Yes, I did that but when I copy and paste the setting into the user settings the setting gets copy-pasted but I am not allowed to edit it. The backspace function does not work. eg: when I want to change the font size I copy-pasted that setting into workspace setting but I am not able to change the font size from 14 to 16

Comment: Try running VS Code as administrator and try to change the settings.